# Simple JSON Object not Evaluating in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong with this class.  It is not evaluating the raw string back to a JSON Type in Javascript and I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong.  When I run it through JS Lint it says that it is valid JSON.

Heres the Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pGygM/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues...

- jQuery isn't selected as the language in jsFiddle.
- When using `eval()` to pass, wrap it in parenthesis so `eval()` doesn't think it's simply a block.
- jQuery has `$.parseJSON()`, use that instead.
- You have an array with a named key - that is not an array, but an object, and invalid JSON.
- `alert()` won't help you debug the object as it will implicitly call `toString()` on the object, returning `'[object Object]'` which isn't too useful. Use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: And a an array opener, "[", is mismatched with an object closer, "}". Looks like you missed pressing Shift in a couple places, maybe?

Comment: Here's an updated JSFiddle with alex & zostay's comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XcyNk/

Answer (score 0):

JSON is wrong in cameras section. Check this

http://jsbin.com/ixucil/edit#javascript,html

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="testID" value='{
  "smo": {
    "grid_columns": 3,
    "grid_rows": 3,
    "cameras": {
        "camera": {
            "camera_id": 1,
            "row": 1,
            "column": 1
        }
    }
  }
}' />​
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
 var txtVal = $('#testID').val(),
 obj = $.parseJSON(txtVal);
 console.log(obj);
})
```